# Node.js C++ -- retrieve website synchronously

Tags: c++, node.js

using the `node.h` header together with [npm-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp) which allows for the creation of C++ modules to work with node.js, how can I get the content of a webpage, similarly to how the `request` module works, except in C++?

The reason I want it in C++ is because I want to get the data synchronously, a.k.a.:

```
var websiteData = myRequest("http://example.com/someJsonInfo.json");
```

which I've heard is (easier/) possible in C++.

So first, if someone knows how to do this without C++, that would suffice.

If not, how can I even begin to get the content of a webpage with the node.h header in C++? The source for it is [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node.h), but I would think that if it's possible in a way that's not built in to http.get, someone would have done it already...

Comment: "The reason I want it in C++ is because I want to get the data synchronously" Can you explain this

Comment: @JanithKasun there's not an (easy) way with plain node.js to get a web request synchronously, i.e.: var jsonCOntent = getSync("example.com/api.js"), you usually have to go through a callback which can get annoying. THere are some node modules which attempt to make the callback process easier, or even have very slow synchronous methods, but I heard in another comment here that the real way to do it is to write a node function in C++, since C++ is generally used for synchronous things

Comment: if you are open to suggestions, please check out this module `https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise`. You can simply use `await` keyword in node js to avoid callback and getting code complicated. In my opinion this is the most convenient to solve your problem.

Comment: @JanithKasun I'd like to do it without await

Comment: @JanithKasun also on the npm site I'm not sure where it says that the request can be used automatically with await, it looks like you need to do .then